# Batch file not processing variable in for loop

Tags: windows, batch, services

I've been working on improving this batch file. My goal is for it to stop the first service in the list and wait until it fully stops, or kill it if it doesn't stop quickly, then start it back up, and wait until the service is fully started before stopping the next service in the list.

As shown in this example, it first writes the name of each service to a file, then reads them. It should be putting them in the %%a field but instead it's putting in Service_%a as the name of the service, and then failing.

How can I change it so that it reads the correct name?

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO ---------------------------------------------->> log.txt
ECHO -----------========================----------->> log.txt
ECHO -----------=========%date%=========----------->> log.txt
ECHO -----------========================----------->> log.txt
ECHO ---------------------------------------------->> log.txt

set DD=0
Set TIMESTAMP="eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=/, "
For /F %TIMESTAMP% %%i in ('DATE /t') DO (
  SET YYYYMMDD=%%l%%j%%k
  SET YYYYMM=%%l%%j
  set DD=%%k
)

echo 3050 >> services
echo 3051 >> services
echo 3052 >> services

for /f %%a in (services) do (
  set timestamp=!date!!time!
  ECHO !timestamp! - Stopping Service %%a >> log.txt
  sc stop Service_%%a >> log.txt
  timeout /t 15 > NUL
  for /f "tokens=4" %%s in ('sc query "Service_%%a" ^| find "STATE"') do if NOT "%%s"=="STOPPED" goto ForceStop
  goto Start

  :ForceStop
  ECHO !timestamp! - Service could not be stopped, forcing... >> log.txt
  taskkill /f /im Service_%%a.exe >> log.txt

  :Start
  ECHO !timestamp! - Service is stopped >> log.txt

  timeout /t 5 > NUL

  set timestamp=!date!!time!
  ECHO !timestamp! - Starting Service %%a >> log.txt
  sc start "Service_%%a" >> log.txt

  :WAIT
  ECHO !timestamp! - Service not yet started >> log.txt
  timeout /t 5 > NUL
  for /f "tokens=4" %%s in ('sc query "Service_%%a" ^| find "STATE"') do if NOT "%%s"=="RUNNING" goto WAIT
  ECHO !timestamp! - Service is started >> log.txt  
)
if exist services del services
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo 3050 >> services
         ^              remove this evil space
```

because although `sc query "Service_3050"` could work, `sc query "Service_3050 "` with that additional space will raise next error:

```
[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

There is another *severe* error in your code: using `:label` *inside* a `(`code block in parentheses`)` will break a `for` loop context. Use `call :label` instead as follows:

```
for /f %%a in (services) do (
  set timestamp=!date!!time!
  ECHO !timestamp! - Stopping Service %%a >> log.txt
  sc stop Service_%%a >> log.txt
  timeout /t 15 > NUL
  for /f "tokens=4" %%s in ('
        sc query "Service_%%a" ^| find "STATE"
        ') do if NOT "%%s"=="STOPPED" CALL :ForceStop "%%a%

  ECHO !timestamp! - Service is stopped >> log.txt

  timeout /t 5 > NUL

  set timestamp=!date!!time!
  ECHO !timestamp! - Starting Service %%a >> log.txt
  sc start "Service_%%a" >> log.txt

    call :WAIT "%%a%
)
goto :done

:WAIT
ECHO !timestamp! - Service not yet started >> log.txt
timeout /t 5 > NUL
for /f "tokens=4" %%s in ('
    sc query "Service_%~1" ^| find "STATE"
    ') do if NOT "%%s"=="RUNNING" goto :WAIT
ECHO !timestamp! - Service is started >> log.txt  
exit /B

:ForceStop
ECHO !timestamp! - Service could not be stopped, forcing... >> log.txt
taskkill /f /im Service_%~1.exe >> log.txt
exit /B

:done
if exist services del services
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~a`, `%~1` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`>>`, `2>1` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: OK, this got me a lot closer. Now the problem I'm running into is that outside of the for loop, the value from the services file is not carrying over. Service %%a is showing as Service %a outside of the first for loop.

Comment: @BrianHenson Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea maxima culpa!